# Formatting output (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with formating this so the output comes out like the picture below (the part in green text). I'm working on myprogramminglabs. I appreciate the help.

```
#Define the main() function.

def main():
    #Open the file "golf.txt".
    file_obj = open("golf.txt")

    #Read all the lines from the file.
    lines = file_obj.readlines()

    #Run the loop to traverse
    #the list containing the lines.
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        #Every even index in the
        #list is the name of a player.

        if i%2 == 0:
            print("Name:"+ lines[i])
        else:
            print("Score:"+ lines[i])

    #Print a blank at the
    #end of the file.
    print()

#Call the main() function.

main()
```

[image: My output vs the desired output]

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you are encountering? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic in particular expectations regarding "homework help."

Comment: `lines[i]` has a line break at the end. Strip it off.

Comment: @DYZ I appreciate the help, it worked.